# Extending simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a simplex and $Y\subseteq |X|$ a simplicial complex. Can I construct a simplicial complex $X'\supseteq Y$ s.t. $|X'|=|X|$? Can I do it without introducing new vertices apart from $V:=X^{(0)}\cup Y^{(0)}$?

My first idea was to start with $X':=Y$ and repeatedly adding, for each $\sigma\subseteq V$ s.t. $\sigma$ is a nondegenerate simplex and $X'\cup \sigma$ is a simplicial complex, $X':=X'\cup\sigma$. However, does it work?

Comment: You may take as $X'$ the simplex whose vertices are the vertices of $Y$.

Comment: 17786: I don't get it. Could you explain please the idea in more details? Thanks, Peter

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't get it right. What you are asking is whether it is possible to give a triangulation $X'$ of $|X|$ for which $Y$ is a simplicial subcomplex. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. And whether you can do it "algorithmically" and possibly without introducing new vertices. If you have any idea, let me know :-)

Comment: You can do that iff the embedding of $|Y|$ into $|X|$ is **tame** (that's almost the definition of tame).

Comment: Well, I suppose $Y$ is a simplicial complex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the embedding is "identical". However, how to extend it to a simplicial complex covering all $|X|$?